# parse multiple IDs in XML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I try to get the content of the following XML nodes parsed with `$.parseXML()`:

1. content_1
2. content_2

`content = $(this).find('[id="100"]')`

works for every nodes with id="100" which means that I get the content of 1. + 2.

```
content = $(this).find('[id="100" i1="a"]')
```

doesn't work.

Which expression do I need to get only the content of 1.?

Comment: `content = $(this).find('[id="100"][i1="a"]')`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for element with attribute ID 100 and attribute i1 as `a` then

```
content = $(this).find('[id="100"][i1="a"]')
```